# How to prevent queue system of processing more than one job from a queue at once?

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I have a lot of tasks, which should be processed in proper order. I would like to divide them by "type" to different queues. Queues should be created dynamically. Then I would like to start X workers, which will process the tasks from the queues. But there is one important rule – from each queue, only one task should be processed at once. The reason is – each task of the specified type can change the state of the application, so I can't start processing a new task of the same type if the last one hasn't finished.

I would like to use Laravel queue system with Redis driver, but I'm not sure it's able to do that. How to prevent the queue system from taking more than one job from each queue at once? Any ideas?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `supervisor` then this is what you can do in your `.conf` file.

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/html/****/artisan queue:work
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=1  <----- this is what you are looking for
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/****/storage/logs/supervisord.log
```

**numprocs** directive will instruct Supervisor to run 1 queue:work processes and monitor it, automatically restarting it if it fails. ([Laravel Queue Supervisor Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queues#supervisor-configuration))

Comment: But what about the situation, when I need to have more than one worker? For example – 10 queues, and 5 workers. If I understand it correctly, your solution works in one-worker only case. I can duplicate this config, but will it not be possible that more than one worker will take the job from the same queue?

Answer (score 0):

Job chaining allows you to specify a list of queued jobs that should be run in sequence after the primary job has executed successfully. If one job in the sequence fails, the rest of the jobs will not be run. To execute a queued job chain, you may use the `withChain` method on any of your dispatchable jobs.

If you would like to specify the default connection and queue that should be used for the chained jobs, you may use the `allOnConnection` and `allOnQueue` methods.

```php
ProcessPodcast::withChain([
    new OptimizePodcast,
    new ReleasePodcast
])->dispatch()->allOnConnection('redis')->allOnQueue('podcasts');
```

See [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues#job-chaining) for more info.

Comment: It's not my case. In my case, every job is the same. It makes some calculation and changes the state of the app. Here is an example scenario – task A change status of the application to "suspended". And the B does some calculation only if the status of the app is "active". So if there is a case, that two workers process task from process simultaneous, and task B will start before task A is finished, everything will be messed up.

Comment: @KrzysztofSzala You want that job B be run after job A has finished right? So the answer is job chaining, I don't understand your case without showing me some of your code.

Comment: Ok, maybe I didn't explain it clearly. Job A and Job B are te same jobs but have a different payload. Treat it like user actions. We have StoreUserActionJob and it process message from the queue. First message changes status to "suspended", so the next one should be rejected by the app. But if the queue system starts proceeding both messages at the same time, the second one could be finished earlier. And this is an undesirable situation for me.